# Determine whether the set $X=\{(a,b) : |b|>e^a \}\subset \mathbb R^2$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Determine whether the set (as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$) is connected.

$$X=\{(a,b) : |b|>e^a \}$$

Thoughts: Not sure how to go about this question. I suppose look for a partition. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: There's an absolute $|\cdot|$, so probably you can divide it into "positive"  and "negative" part.

Comment: @John I don't understand. Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Did you try dawning out $X$?

Comment: @John yes I did try but really can't visualise it to draw it. What sort of partition are you thinking?

Comment: For example, is $(a, 0)$ in $X$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$X=\left\{(a,b)\;;\;b<-e^a\right\}\cup\left\{(a,b)\;;\;b>e^a\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:** The region $X$ is the set of points that are above the curve of equation $y=e^x$, or below the curve of equation $y=-e^x$. Hence $X$ can be written as $\{(a,b)\mid b>0, b>e^a\}\cup\{(a,b)\mid b<0, b<-e^a\}$, the union being disjoint. If you can show that these two sets are open, $X$ is not connected and you are done.

> **Final hint:** $\{(a,b)\mid b>0, b>e^a\} = \{(a,b)\mid b>0\}\cap X$.

Comment: I think it isn't necessary to write $\;b<0\;,\;\;b>0\;$ in each part of those sets as $\;e^x>0\;$ always.

Comment: @Timbuc: indeed, I just thought that extra detail may help the OP to help him visualize what $X$ is. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @rosebud So I have to show these sets are the intersection of $X$ with an open set of $R^2$. What is a basis for $R^2$? That might help

Comment: A basis for $\mathbb R^2$ is the family of open discs, for example (i.e. the sets of the form $\{(x,y) \mid (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 < a\}$ for some $a>0$ and $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb R^2$). Another basis is the family of open boxes: sets of the form $\{(x,y)\mid a<x<b, c<y<d\}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers.

Comment: @Rosebud so the first set is the intersection of $X$ with a union of boxes with $c=e^a$?

Comment: Well, you can take $c=0$ here, since $e^a$ is positive. But you are on the right track, with union of boxes can you express the set $\{(x,y) \in\mathbb R^2\mid y>0\}$?

Comment: but that's not the condition. The condition is $y>e^x$

Comment: See my edit. Remember that we want these two sets to be X intersected with an open set of $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, consider the following approach. In $\Bbb R^2$ the set is connected iff it is path connected. We know that points $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$ are in $X$, so that there must exist a point $(a,0)\in X$, which is clearly impossible by definition of $X.